Detect user voice frequency with webAudio context API (or any other API for browser)
The below code is working fine but it has some issues due to which frequency varies a lot. I think this is because I am not removing the distortion or the silence frequency. let's assume I started the mic to listen and then I am reading a paragraph, so the frequency of words is coming correct (I think so as per my observation) but when I pause in between then also it is capturing the frequency(which is higher than while speaking). I need the output value in Freq Hz. please help me with this thank you.
var voiceFreqArray = [];

function getMedia() {
  navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
  navigator.getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true }, callback, console.log);
}
function callback(stream) {
  var ctx = new AudioContext();
  var mic = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  var analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
  mic.connect(analyser);
  var data = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  function play() {
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(data);
    var idx = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < analyser.frequencyBinCount; j++) {
      if (data[j] > data[idx]) {
        idx = j;
      }
    }
    var frequency = idx * ctx.sampleRate / analyser.fftSize;
    ob = frequency;
    myReq = requestAnimationFrame(play);
    //console.log(idx, ctx.sampleRate, analyser.fftSize);
    if (ob > 85 && ob < 255) {
      voiceFreqArray.push(ob);
      //console.log("print", ob, myReq);}else{
      //console.log("excluded", ob, myReq);
    }
  }
  play();
  //stop Media stream
  mediaStream = stream;
  mediaStream.stop = function () {
    this.getAudioTracks().forEach(function (track) {
      track.stop();
    });
    this.getVideoTracks().forEach(function (track) { //in case... :)
      track.stop();
    });
  };
}

function stopMedia() {
  mediaStream.stop();
}
function getFreq() {
  console.log(voiceFreqArray.reduce((x, y) => x + y) / voiceFreqArray.length);
  //document.getElementById("val1").value = ob;
  document.getElementById("val1").value = voiceFreqArray.reduce((x, y) => x + y) / voiceFreqArray.length;
  mediaStream.stop();
  cancelAnimationFrame(myReq);
  // Stop processing audio stream
  //mic.disconnect(analyser);
}

